# Scala/Java: Generating a set of non-repeating random numbers

Tags: java, scala, random

I need to randomly sample a subset of n elements from a list in Scala, and I was wondering if there was a convenient way to do so without recourse to manually checking that each of the n elements are unique. At the moment I have something like this:

```
import util.Random

def sample(itms:List[A], sampleSize:Int) {
  var numbersSeen = Set[Int]()
  var sampled = List[A]()
  val itmLen = itms.size()
  var sampleIdex = Random.nextInt(itmLen)
  while(sampled < sampleSize) {
    if(numbersSeen.contains(sampleIdex)){
      sampleIdex = Random.nextInt(itmLen)
    } else {
      numbersSeen.add(sampleIdex)
      sampled.add(itms(sampleIdex))
    }
  }
  sampled
}
```

I was hoping there was something more elegant that can be done to either generate a non-repeating random list of integers in a range or to randomly sample n elements from a list.

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal The subset should be unique in the sense that there shouldn't be any element from the original list sampled more than once.

Comment: Shuffle the list and pop elements into the subset

Comment: Try using "System.currentTimeMillis" as a seed ;)

Comment: @MattBall The algorithm there is suitable in general, but I'd like to avoid mutating the list.

Comment: Oh, hello from Wickenden `:)`

Comment: @TriangleMan: you don't have to mutate it to get a version sorted by a random number (as described in Rex's answer below)

Comment: Stream.continually(Random.nextInt(itms.size)).distinct.take(sampleSize).map(itms)

Answer (score 5):

If your list is not too long you could shuffle a list of index numbers and then march through that list.

In Scala that would be something like:

```
val aList = ('A' to 'Z').toList

val aListIterator = scala.util.Random.shuffle((0 until aList.length).toList).toIterator
```

and then in your looping structure:

```
...
if( aListIterator.hasNext ) aList(aListIterator.next)
...
```

If your list is huge, a function that returns a unique random number in the range of your list size (used as an index) might be a better approach.  Jeff Preshing, recently blogged about unique random numbers, http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can pick one randomly, and sample from the list except the one you've just picked, with simpleSize-1 (tail-)recursively:

```
    def sample[A](itms:List[A], sampleSize:Int) = {

        def collect(vect: Vector[A], sampleSize: Int, acc : List[A]) : List[A] = {
            if (sampleSize == 0) acc
            else {
                val index = Random.nextInt(vect.size)
                collect( vect.updated(index, vect(0)) tail, sampleSize - 1, vect(index) :: acc)
            }
        }

        collect(itms toVector, sampleSize, Nil)
    }                                 //> sample: [A](itms: List[A], sampleSize: Int)List[A]


    sample(1 to 10 toList, 5)         //> res0: List[Int] = List(6, 8, 2, 1, 10)
```

Comment: This is `O(n*k)` where `n` is the length of the list and `k` is the number of items.  Not a good choice unless `k < log(n`).

Comment: I think the collect part is only O(k), considering all the vector operations take effective constant times and collect is called k times (k=sampleSize). There is a one time O(n) operation (toVector) at first but its only adds O(n), not multiplies.

Comment: sample(itms, sampleSize) takes a bit less than a sec on my comp with n  = 1 000 000 and k = 100 000

Comment: You're right--I made a mistake about where the vector and list operations were.  Sorry!

Comment: Np :)         12345678912

Answer (score 1):

```
itms.map(x => (x, util.Random.nextDouble)).sortBy(_._2).take(sampleSize).map(_._1)
```

as long as you don't care about the inefficiency of sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a random sample from the set of subsets, i.e.:

```
val distinctSubsets = itms.to[Set].subsets(sampleSize)
```

Then choose one of those randomly.

Answer (score -1):

What about this approach?

```
trait RandomOrdering[T] extends Ordering[T]

object RandomOrdering {
  implicit def defaultOrdering[T] = new RandomOrdering[T] {
    def compare(x:T, y:T) = (Random nextInt 3) - 1
  }
}

def sample[A](items:List[A], sampleSize:Int)(implicit r:RandomOrdering[A]) =
  items.sorted take sampleSize
```

It might be less performant but it also allows you to inject a different `RandomOrdering`.

Comment: An ordering that gives random answers is not guaranteed to produce a randomly sorted set of numbers.  (In particular, it's a disaster for insertion sort, which almost all sorts default to for small numbers.)

Comment: I do not understand, what do you mean? Using OP's method I could in theory also get a list of the same ordering as the original. If I am missing something please enlighten me.

Comment: Every element should be equally likely to be the first element in your list, regardless of how they're sorted or compared.  This is not true at all for your solution.  You will produce a rather scrambled order, but not random.